# Remove all the digits and make Blank ,in the following URLS

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, str-replace

I have below URL
https:///scorecard?CompetitionId=1980&Number ID=8300

https://scorecard?CompetitionId=1563&FixtureId=3400

and I want to replace with below ones

https:///scorecard?CompetitionId= & Number ID=

https://scorecard?CompetitionId=&FixtureId=

Comment: You could use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: it would be nice if you give source code, since i am new to this

Comment: You might want to explain what you didn't understand when you read the documentation. StackOverflow isn't meant to be a tutoring service. [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) allows you to split everything in parts. Now you're task is to construct a new URL from those parts.

Comment: i am not in to coding actually , i am business analyst . i am  sorry but i am looking for only  direct solutions . Thank you